# Relationship with another Entity when using inheritance on parent class or on child classes

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, entity-framework-core

I have the following inheritance. A doctor is a parent class. A doctor can be a paediatrician, a dentist or an orthopaedic. Each doctor type have different properties (different domain logic) but they all share the same Id, Name and they also all can have many appointments.

```
public abstract class Doctor
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Paediatrician : Doctor
{
    // add some other properties specific only to Paediatrician.
}

public class Orthopaedic : Doctor
{
    // add some other properties specific only to Orthopaedic.
}

public class Dentist : Doctor
{
    // add some other properties specific only to Dentist.
} 

public class Appointment
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfAppointment { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

There is a one to many relationship here (a doctor can have many appointments). Question here is where do I add the Appointment relationship? Inside each child class or on the parent class? I have to set this relationship to my ORM so adding this relationship into each child class would produce three different relationships into my db whereas if I add it to the parent class only one? The same stands for Country table. Where do I add Country relationship? Only on the parent class or child classes?
One of the systems requirement that might affect my selection is that I have is to show a list view with the name of the doctor and the appointment date. So there are two ways of doing this. Either by calling each child class and aggregate the results or by calling parent class directly and get the appointments if I add the Appointment relationship to the parent class. I am stuck and don't know what is the correct way of doing this fundamentally.

Comment: Paragraphs are free on stackoverflow

Comment: This is not really a programming question, but more a relational database question. However, [inheritance is described in the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance). (In recent years the Microsoft docs have become quite good (compared to the past).) I think the table-per-hierarchy can become quite big if there are mutliple derivatives. Table-per-type seems more logical, although there's an extra level of indirection, which has inferior performance (see bottom comment on page).

Comment: @JHBonarius but even in TPT where do common relationships are added? In the parent class or child classes. The document of EF Core does not state such a scenario (most of the examples in general show very simple examples) leaving the more complex scenarios with a big questionmark

Comment: I'll improve my answer later. But to my best knowledge, the list of appointments should be in the base. Why wouldn't it? Just as id and name are common... why would the common list be different?

Comment: If it is in the base can I query the base class directly? Isn't the purpose of the inheritance to hide the base class and work with the child classes only?

Comment: yes, but the derivived class **inherits** those properties. that's the point of inheritance. Else accessing a dentist "name" would als not be possible, right?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not specific for C# .Net or entity framework, but it's generally about object relationships.

The first point is inheritance. A derived class inherits all public and protected properties (and has access to methods with the same qualifiers) from the base class. I.e. A `Dentist` will also have an `Id` and a `Name`, although you don't declare them in the class. They are inherited from `Doctor`.

The second point is object relations. Clearly a `Dentist` can make an `Appointment` and so can a `Paediatrician`. And both are a type of `Doctor`. As you state, there's a one-to-many relationship. The "many" is the `Appointment`, but what do you want the "one" to be? Of course you can choose it to be `Dentist` or `Paediatrician`. But you'll have to make an appointment a generic class

```
    public class Appointment<T> where T : Doctor
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime DateOfAppointment { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public T DoctorNavigation { get; set; }
    }
```

Each derived class would then have its own appointment list

```
    public class Dentist : Doctor
    {
        ...
        public List<Appointment<Dentist>> DentistAppointments { get; set; }
    }
```

However, I would expect that there's only one list of `Appointment`s, for which the "one" relationship is a `Doctor`. Of course, you could still give each Derived class its own list of appointments, but that would cause a strange `Appointment` entity, which has an optional navigation property to each of the derived classes.

More logically, you would put the list of `Appointment`s in the `Doctor` (base) class.

<s>You will need to add a Discriminator to be able to map back from `Doctor` to a derivative.</s>
Hmm, the discriminator doesn't work for TPT... trying to figure out how to do this.

Comment: TPH creates a mess. I m not using it as my domain contains dozens of other properties in each child class. That is why I am using TPT although it might create some perf issues it is more clear

Comment: @pantonis "dozens of other properties in each child class" <- are you sure there's not an architecture issue there?

Comment: No. Each type of doctor has its own business logic (e.g orthopaedic has X-Rays, dentist has Teeth operations etc...) and all doctor types are doctors (fulfil the 'is a' for inheritance)

Comment: @pantonis update. please let me know what else you need